# Decimal to binary code-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn Javascript. Why this is not working?

```js
function test() {
  var x,z;
  $x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  $z = ($x).toString(2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $z;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="test()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Browser don't inser binary number but it inser what is in input.

Comment: So you trying to convert the input number to binary number and then insert in `p`?

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

Your `$x` is a string, not a number.

To convert it to a number, you can use the [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29).

Then, `toString(2)` will work:

```js
function test() {
  var $x = +document.getElementById("input").value,
      $z = $x.toString(2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $z;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="test()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: + though I will prefer to use `(+$x).toString(2);` where I need `$x`  as int

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `$x` to `int` by `parseInt()` this way...

```
$z = (parseInt($x)).toString(2);
```

Modified Function...

```
function test() {
        var x,z;
        $x = +document.getElementById("input").value;
        $z = ($x).toString(2);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $z;
    }
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/0wy6tjqp/17/)**